# How do I localize web part title?

Tags: 2010, web-part, localization, resource-files

I'm adding a bunch of web parts to a page using a module like this:

```
    <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="TopLeftRow" WebPartOrder="1">
    <![CDATA[
        <webParts>
          <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
            <metaData>
              <type name="SiteDef.MyTasks_wp.MyTasks_wp, SiteDef, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fppbar" />
              <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
            </metaData>
            <data>
              <properties>
                <property name="Title" type="string">$Resources:Resources,MyTasks</property>
              </properties>
            </data>
           </webPart>
        </webParts>
    ]]>
  </AllUsersWebPart>
```

I've deployed my resource file as a provisioning resource since runtime resources seem to have no effect. The localization works after provisioning but if I switch language the original localization is persisted.

Is there a way to localize a web part's title so that it adapts to the end user's language preferences?

Comment: why don't use code behind for localizing title ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491702(v=office.14).aspx